# Needs an elaboration of how Ansible works when pushing configuration to remote nodes

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I can find tons of introduction of Ansible but can hardly find one explain my simple question in a fine grained level. I also understand the big picture how ansible works. So, firstly, please correct me if my following description is wrong:

When executing Ansible to run the task, underneath the local machine (e.g. my laptop) where Ansible code is maintained pushes the Ansible configuration file to remote nodes (defined in inventory) via SSH connection, then those remote nodes will run ansible tasks. （At least all the Ansible tutorials I saw are saying this.）

If my above description is correct. **My simple question is** what is the location/path on remote nodes that ansible pushes the configuration file to? Especially when thinking that Ansible is agent-less. If there is a default location, what is that? Can I specify the location of remote nodes to where the configuration file should be pushed?

Comment: There is not always a file, see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-pipelining https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-keep-remote-files and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/examples/ansible.cfg#L17

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"What is the location/path on remote nodes that Ansible pushes the configuration file to?"***

A: It depends on the module. As a hint, take a look at the obsolete list of [Files modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/list_of_files_modules.html#files-modules) in Ansible 2.8. Since then no such list is maintained because it's out of scope to keep up will all [collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index.html).

- Some parameters *dest* require an absolute path. For example, the parameter [*dest*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#ansible-builtin-copy-module-copy-files-to-remote-locations) of the *copy* module:

> Remote absolute path where the file should be copied to.

- The *$PWD* is the default path if a module doesn't require an absolute path. Then, the *$PWD* depends on how you [connect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#connection-plugins) to the remote hosts. For example, if you ssh to the remote host as *admin*

```yaml
    - block:
        - command: whoami
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
        - command: pwd
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: admin
  out.stdout: /home/admin
```

In many cases you have to [escalate privilege](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation) and become *root*. This doesn't change $PWD

```yaml
    - block:
        - command: whoami
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
        - command: pwd
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
      become: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: root
  out.stdout: /home/admin
```

For example, the modules

- [*file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#ansible-builtin-file-module-manage-files-and-file-properties)
- [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-module-manage-lines-in-text-files)
- [*blockinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html)

operate by default on *$PWD*

```yaml
    - block:
        - file:
            dest: test_file
            state: touch
        - lineinfile:
            dest: test_file
            line: test line
        - blockinfile:
            dest: test_file
            block: |
              test line1 in block
              test line2 in block
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
```

give

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /home/admin/test_file
test line
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
test line1 in block
test line2 in block
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Comment: Thanks, do I understand correctly that on the local machine, it just push the ansible files to the remote node, and then, on remote node, the ansible modules are then downloaded & tasks are executed?

Comment: Yes. See [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html). You can easily learn all details.